# VBScript inconsistent Column count

Tags: vbscript

Being I'm a novice at VBS, I'm have a hard time determining why this short script is not returning a column count of 193, One time I'll get the correct count and others I get 0.
Thank you in advance for any and all suggestions.

OldCityCat

```
Sub VerifyOrders
Dim Results
Dim objFSO, objTextFile, objReadFile, Contents, objFile

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("C:\TestFileWith_194_characters.csv")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\TestFileWith_194_characters.csv")

Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\TestFileWith_194_characters.csv",1) 
    objReadFile.ReadAll

     Contents = objReadFile.Column -1

WScript.Echo Contents

    If Contents < 194 Then
        Results = "No Orders"
    Else
        Results = "Has Orders"
    End if
objReadFile.Close

    If Results = "No Orders" Then
        Call NoOrders
    Else
        Call OpenAccess
    End If
End Sub

'/ If no orders the send email end script. Else If orders process them
Sub NoOrders
If Results = "No Orders" Then
   Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
   objMail.Display
   objMail.Recipients.Add ("gchichester@wilk.us.com")
   objMail.Subject = "No Sales Orders to Process"
   objMail.Body = "Respect didn't receive any orders for Pine Castle"
   objMail.Send   
   objOutlook.Quit
Set objMail = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
End If

End Sub

Sub OpenAccess
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE "&" C:\DropBox\Inflow\DrugSales.accdb /x OnOpen")
        WScript.Sleep 60000
        WshShell.SendKeys "%{F4}" 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `0` when the contents of the text file you're reading from has written a newline character, but nothing else.

**From the Microsoft documentation:**

> After a newline character has been written, but before any other character is written, Column is equal to 1.

Throughly examine the contents of the text file before you attempt to read it in as a text stream.

**Of note but not relevant to my answer above:** you do not need to declare or set `objFile` or `objTextFile` since you are using `objReadFile`.  Suggest removing both the declaration and `set` operations for both of those variables.

Comment: Robert, By default the file has 194 characters, I'm trying to test if more data has been added,

Comment: I've worked out my original issue by checking if a new line was added which seems to be working. Again as a novice to VBScript but have been coding in VBA for a few years. I have issues with using Sub's. I have checked several online sources and they all  resemble VBA, but when I add the Sub/End Sub to my code it doesn't run at all from with my editor, no errors, just doesn't run. Remove Sub/End Sub runs fine. Also I'm calling sub's with inconsistent results